# Apply boxcox function to a data frame group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, apply

I have the a function that applies a box-cox transformation to an array and a data frame that I'd like to group and apply the transformation to:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

def boxcox(*args) -> np.array:
    return stats.boxcox(*args)[0] # return only the first element of the tuple

data = {'id': [1,1,1,2,2,2], 'quantity': [1,10,2,5,6,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Where the data frame looks like this:

```
   id  quantity
0   1         1
1   1        10
2   1         2
3   2         5
4   2         6
5   2         5
```

I want to group by id and then apply the declared function and add the results to a new column, quantity_multiplied:

```
df['quantity_boxcox'] = df.groupby('id')['quantity'].apply(boxcox)
```

However this doesn't work as expected, I get this:

```
   id  quantity                                    quantity_boxcox
0   1         1                                                NaN
1   1        10                [0.00000000, 1.47091335, 0.60069922]
2   1         2                [0.08483521, 0.08483521, 0.08483521]
3   2         5                                                NaN
4   2         6                                                NaN
5   2         5                                                NaN
```

whereas I want:

```
   id  quantity   quantity_boxcox
0   1         1        0.00000000
1   1        10        1.47091335
2   1         2        0.60069922
3   2         5        0.08483521
4   2         6        0.08483521
5   2         5        0.08483521
```

How do I get the above data frame, please?

Comment: Why not simply use `df['quantity'] * 2`?

Comment: The way the problem is currently setup it seems like `df['quantity_multiplied'] = df['quantity'] * 2` would be the correct answer. Is this a simplification of a more complex problem?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma The function in practice is a bit more complicated – see the edit, please.

Comment: @HenryEcker Please see the edit, the function is more complicated than initially stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a [`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-transform) operation instead:

```
def boxcox(s) -> np.array:
    return stats.boxcox(s)[0]

df['quantity_boxcox'] = df.groupby('id')['quantity'].transform(boxcox)
```

Transform "produc[es] a like-indexed DataFrame on each group and return[s] a DataFrame having the same indexes as the original object filled with the transformed values". Any iterable produced by transform is acceptable and will populate in direct order per group. This function is useful when turning some data into a collection of the same size that is not indexed (like an `np.array` or `list`).

`df`:

```
   id  quantity  quantity_boxcox
0   1         1         0.000000
1   1        10         1.470913
2   1         2         0.600699
3   2         5         0.084835
4   2         6         0.084835
5   2         5         0.084835
```

---

A slower option would be to turn the result into a [`Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html#pandas-series) with appropriate indexes and feed with [`groupby apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-apply):

```
def boxcox(s) -> np.array:
    return pd.Series(stats.boxcox(s)[0], index=s.index)

df['quantity_boxcox'] = df.groupby('id')['quantity'].apply(boxcox)
```

`df`:

```
   id  quantity  quantity_boxcox
0   1         1         0.000000
1   1        10         1.470913
2   1         2         0.600699
3   2         5         0.084835
4   2         6         0.084835
5   2         5         0.084835
```

---

Timing Information:

```
%timeit df.groupby('id')['quantity'].transform(lambda s: stats.boxcox(s)[0])
2.51 ms ± 63.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```
%timeit df.groupby('id')['quantity'].apply(lambda s: pd.Series(stats.boxcox(s)[0], index=s.index))
2.78 ms ± 161 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `multiply` function as follows to achieve what you want.

```py
def multiply(*args):
    return 2.0 * args[0]
```

The output is:

```py
id  quantity  quantity_multiplied
1         1                  2.0
1        10                 20.0
1         2                  4.0
2         5                 10.0
2         6                 12.0
2         5                 10.0
```

---

Update:

Since your function is a bit more complex, then you can modify it as follows to get the desired result.

```py
def boxcox(*args) -> np.array:
    return pd.Series(stats.boxcox(*args)[0], index=args[0].index)
```

The output is:

```py
   id  quantity   quantity_boxcox
0   1         1        0.00000000
1   1        10        1.47091335
2   1         2        0.60069922
3   2         5        0.08483521
4   2         6        0.08483521
5   2         5        0.08483521
```

Comment: The function is actually a bit more complicated so this approach doesn't work.

Comment: @alex_lewis I have updated the answer, it now solves your updated situation as well.